# Rails, Puma, Postgres: Preloading Active Record definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, puma

After every boot, I see queries like these to the database:

[image]

Once each puma worker is hit once with a request (that hits the database), these go away. It's annoying because it can add 50+ sql queries to a request (1s +). What I want to do is somehow preload these every time a worker boots.

I've tried

```
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
  Rails.application.eager_load!
  ::Rails::Engine.subclasses.map(&:instance).each { |engine| engine.eager_load! }
  ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
end
```

Which does not work.

I have both

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
```

set in my environment.

I'm expecting there to be some sort of rails setting that does this - seems like a smart thing to do by default in production?

Comment: `rails` does eager_load all the controllers, models, helpers, etc in the production mode. Not sure why it is not working. By looking at the image, looks like something else is triggering those sql queries. Can you post the `EventPromotersController` class, especially `load_event`.

Comment: I can't post  that code -- but I'm doing nothing out of the ordinary, just standard ActiveRecord.find and also heavy use of the IdentityCache gem. No matter what code I have in there though, I can't think of a legitimate reason for these queries to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24133

Rails 5 will have improvements, but you still currently need to do:

```
# https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24133
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  con = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  filename = File.join(ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.db_dir, "schema_cache.dump")

  con.schema_cache.clear!
  con.data_sources.each { |table| con.schema_cache.add(table) }
  open(filename, 'wb') { |f| f.write(Marshal.dump(con.schema_cache)) }
end
```

in an initializer.